# Can we solve a set of equations?

Tags: numerical-methods, soft-question

Not sure if the following set of equation are solvable. $x_i$ are known and $y_i$ are unknown. The relation between them is:

$$\frac{[y_{i+1}-y_i][1+(y_{i+1}-y_i)^2]^{3/2}}{y_{i+2}-y_i}=\frac{1}{2}[x_{i+2}-x_i]$$

where $i$ is an index and it goes from 1 to say n. So we have $n-2$ set of equations $n$ unknowns and $n$ known variables. Can we solve for $y_i$ here? Is it solvable, if so what tool can I use? If it is not solvable do we need another set of equations to solve? Any comments would be appreciate.

Edit: Do we have $n-2$ equations as we loose 1 eqations each in the boundary?

Comment: The relation gives $y_{i+2}$ in terms of $y_{i+1}$ and $y_i$. So, once you choose $y_1$ and $y_2$ you can calculate $y_3, y_4, \dots, y_n$ in terms of $y_1, y_2$ and $x_j$.

Comment: @dxiv You mean we have to assume first two values or any 2 values?

Comment: You have $n-2$ equations with $n$ unknowns, so the system is underdetermined. You'll have to choose two arbitrary values, and given the form of the relation it's easier to calculate if you chose the first two, because $y_{i+2}$ is the only variable that factors linearly in the equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Letting
$a_i = x_{i+1}-x_i
$
and
$b_i
=y_{i+1}-y_i
$,

$\dfrac{[y_{i+1}-y_i][1+(y_{i+1}-y_i)^2]^{3/2}}{y_{i+2}-y_i}=\dfrac{1}{2}[x_{i+2}-x_i]
$
becomes
$\dfrac{b_i(1+b_i^2]^{3/2}}{b_{i+1}+b_i}=\dfrac{a_{i+1}+a_i}{2}
$
so
$b_{i+1}
=\dfrac{2b_i(1+b_i^2]^{3/2}}{a_{i+1}+a_i}-b_i
=b_i\left(\dfrac{2(1+b_i^2]^{3/2}}{a_{i+1}+a_i}-1\right)
$
or
$y_{i+2}-y_{i+1}
=(y_{i+1}-y_i)\left(\dfrac{2(1+(y_{i+1}-y_i)^2]^{3/2}}{x_{i+2}-x_i}-1\right)
$
or
$y_{i+2}
=y_{i+1}+(y_{i+1}-y_i)\left(\dfrac{2(1+(y_{i+1}-y_i)^2]^{3/2}}{x_{i+2}-x_i}-1\right)
$.

Starting with an arbitrary
$y_1$ and $y_2$,
the successive
$y_i$
can then be gotten.